# Method undefined for type JList - Where to place method?

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm trying to call a method on a JList, but I get this "method undefined for JList" error. The problem is I don't know where the method should go. This is the code without the method:

```
public class Jp_Diskussion extends JPanel {
    private Jd_BeitragErstellen jd_beitr_erst;
    private Jd_BeitragBearbeiten jd_beitr_bearb;
    private JFrame parentFrame = (JFrame) this.getParent();
    private JComboBox comboBoxMA;
    private JComboBox comboBoxTag;
    private JButton btnFiltern;
    private JLabel labelFiltern;
    private JLabel labelOpt;
    private JButton btnBeitragVerfassen;
    private JScrollPane messageScroll;
    private JList messageList;
    private DefaultListModel messageModel;

public Jp_Diskussion() {
    createMessageList();
}

public void getMessage(String author, String text, String date, String tag) {
     messageModel.addElement(new Message(author, text, date, tag));
}

private void createMessageList() {
    setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 994, 624));
    setLayout(null);
    add(getJScrollPane());
    add(getComboBoxTag());
    add(getComboBox_2());
    add(getBtnFiltern());
    add(getLabelFiltern());
    add(getLabelOpt());
    add(getBtnBeitragVerfassen());



    messageList.getMessage("NAME AUTOR", "<html><body style='width: 690px;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", "22.01.13", "SOA");
    messageList.getMessage("AUTOR NAME", "<html><body style='width: 690px;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", "22.01.13", "SOA");

}

private JList getMessageList() {
    if (messageList == null) {
        messageModel = new DefaultListModel();
        messageList = new JList(messageModel);
        messageList.setCellRenderer(new MessageRenderer());     
    }
    return messageList;
}



private JScrollPane getJScrollPane() {
    if (messageScroll == null) {
        messageScroll = new JScrollPane(getMessageList());
        messageScroll.setBounds(20, 20, 954, 461);
    }
    return messageScroll;
}

private JButton getBtnBeitragVerfassen() {

private JLabel getLabelFiltern() {

private JLabel getLabelOpt() {

private JComboBox getComboBoxTag() {
private JComboBox getComboBox_2() {
private JButton getBtnFiltern() {
}
```

And this is the method:

```
public void getMessage(String author, String text, String date, String tag) {
     messageModel.addElement(new Message(author, text, date, tag));
}
```

Now if I define the getMessage method outside of the createMessageList method I get the above error when calling getMessage inside createMessageList. If I define the getMessage method inside the getMessageList method that won't work either because I can't define a method inside another method.

But where should I define it then?

Code Snippet 3:

```
public class MessageList extends JPanel{
  DefaultListModel messageModel = new DefaultListModel();
  JList  messageList = new JList(messageModel);
  JScrollPane     messageScroll = new JScrollPane(messageList);
  MessageRenderer messageRenderer = new MessageRenderer();

     public MessageList( ){
        messageList.setCellRenderer(messageRenderer);

        add(messageScroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
     }

     public void ladeBeitrag(String author, String text, String date, String tag){
         messageModel.addElement(new Message(author, text, date, tag));
     }

     public static void main(String[]args){
         MessageList m = new MessageList(); 
          JFrame f = new JFrame("JPanel inside JList");
          f.setSize(900, 750);
          f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          f.setVisible(true);
          f.add(m);

          m.ladeBeitrag("NAME AUTOR", "<html><body style='width: 690px;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren.", "22.01.13", "SOA");
          m.ladeBeitrag("AUTOR NAME", "<html><body style='width: 690px;'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.", "22.01.13", "SOA");
     } 
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're doing.  You're putting `createMessageList` **inside** `getMessage`?  That doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you're asking about anonymous inner classes?  See:  Sun/Oracle trail on that topic.  When you run it, please copy/paste the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Those method names are so confusing :-( If you look inside createMessageList() I'm calling messageList.getMessage("NAME AUTOR", "<html><bo... two times. But where would I have to put the method getMessageList() for this to work?

Comment: 1.) is this .java file complete?  Is there more code for this class?  2.)  for any Java class, the **order** of the methods doesn't matter.  It doesn't matter whether, in class `Foo`, method `bar` comes before or after `baz`.  3.)  I don't think you're asking about the order or sequence of methods.   4.)  does this compile?  5.)  does it run?

Comment: I've updated the first code snippet with the entire .java file (without imports and some methods collapsed). If I run it with the messageList.getMessage commented out it compiles fine. If I don't comment them out I get the error: The method getMessage(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type JList.

Comment: remove the `getMessageList` method, and, when you need a reference to `messageList`, just use something like `messageList.getMessageModel` (or whatever the syntax is).

Comment: But where do I create the JList then?

Comment: Okay you more or less answered it in you other answer ;-)

Comment: Could you maybe also take a look at the Code Snippet 3 I just updated? There it works just fine. I just don't get the difference.

Comment: `JList  messageList = new JList(messageModel);` is a field.  moved to chat, or I tried to move it to chat.  You can ask on irc, ##java if you have access to freenode irc.  (you need to create an account.)  You need more points or something to chat on SO, clfx, so use IRC for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put more code and stack trace information into your question.

However, I think you might be misapplying the idea of getters/setters.  I don't think that you you want a getter method `getMessageList` to return the a `JList`.  I mean, why?  What calls that method, and what does it do with the reference?

In your `JPanel` or `JFrame`, you probably **want** a `JList` named `messageJList`, that' fine.  However, it doesn't make sense have a `getMessageJList` method because, well, your `JPanel` or `JFrame` **already has it**.  It's a field.

So, don't return a `JList`, it's non-sensical.

Now, in your `JPanel` or `JFrame`, where `messageJList` is a **field**, you certainly might want your `getMessage` method.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Your messageList is a JList:

```
private JList messageList;
```

In method getMessageList you are assigning

```
messageList = new JList(messageModel);
```

So you can call methods that are defined in class JList on your messageList variable.

You are defining method

```
public void getMessage(String author, String text, String date, String tag) {
     messageModel.addElement(new Message(author, text, date, tag));
}
```

in your class Jp_Diskussion so you can call this method on instances of Jp_Diskussion, not on instances of JList.

Comment: And where would I have to define getMessage() to be able to call it on JList?

Comment: Well... you should define a new class that extends JList and define that method in there. Then have your messageList to be an instance of your new class instead of JList

Comment: Hmm but why doesn't it work like in the Code Snippet 3 I just updated. There it works without an extra class that extends JList. Where is the difference?

Comment: you don't **need** to extend `JList` for what you're doing.  The basic idea is that `messageJList` **is a** `JList`.  So, you can just do things like:  get default model.  add/remove to the default model.  update the model of the `JList` when the model changes.  That will serve your purposes.  Now, **if**, and it's a big if, **if** you need more functionality, then make a new class `MyJList` which extends `JList`.  That's the difference between **is-a** and **has-a**.  Generally, use composition, meaning that your `JFrame` **has-a** reference to something....it's a big topic.

Comment: you will probably need to give your JList a new model when you get new data, by the way.  it's swing.

Comment: Code Snippet 3 is pretty different: there you have a variable messageList that is a reference to a JList, and a variable m that is a reference to an instance of class MessageList (mind capital letter... MessageList is the class you are defining... same as Jp_Diskussion in your previous example). You are invoking ladeBeitrag on m, not on messageList. And that is right because method ladeBeitrag is defined in class MessageList, not in class JList... I think the similar names are confusing you.

Comment: ...and I agree with @Thufir on any comment and hint he gave. In general you extend a class to add behaviour (like a new method) but it's true that you should generally prefer composition. You may also want to take a look at the decorator pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern

Comment: time for a new question!  this one's beaten to death :)